# При загрузке картинок по URL picasso в определенный момент просто перестает их подгружать

Tags: android, picasso

При загрузке картинок из интернета с помощью библиотеки `picasso`, какое-то время картинки подгружаются как надо, но в какой-то момент `picasso` перестает работать и вместо незагруженных картинок так и остаются заглушки. С чем может быть связано? Мой адаптер:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Item> objects;

CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = items;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }
    Item p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.textView4)).setText(p.price);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6)).setText(p.brand);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setText(p.model);
    ImageView img= view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(p.image).fit().into(img);

    return view;
}

Item getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Item) getItem(position));
}

}
```

Comment: Окей, пришло понимание, что вероятно проблема в том что на моем телефоне на определенном этапе заканчивается память. Подскажите пжл варианты для оптимизации. Либо может быть можно сделать картинки легче?

Comment: Окей, пришло понимание, что вероятно при этом куда-то уходит помять. Т.к. всего 89 картинок, каждая по ~30кб (т.е все примерно на 3мб). Процесс при этом сжирает 20мб и очевидно готов сожрать больше, т.к. дальше не качает. Косяк должен быть на поверхности, помогайте)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, все действительно оказалось просто и не касается ни адаптера ни даже самого приложения. У меня сервак на Flask торчит наружу через ngrok. Как оказалось, ngrok бесплатно поддерживает только 20 коннектов в минуту. ))